# Some verse of Qur'an said by Devil?

Tags: quran, verses

Is the correct that Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) said that some verse of Qur'an were said be Devil?

Answer (score 2):

Although your question does not provide enough details of where or how you happen to attain this info but here goes my answer:

As you may have seen in the Quran some Ayat are maybe a quote of conversation (Allah knows best), to relate this to your answer i will refer to versus from Surat Al'raf, where god has commanded angels to bow down Adam but Satan has refused:

> 7:11 And We have certainly created you, [O Mankind], and given you [human] form. Then We >said to the angels, "Prostrate to Adam"; so they prostrated, except for Iblis. He was not >of those who prostrated.
>
> 7:12 [ Allah ] said, "What prevented you from prostrating when I commanded you?" [Satan] >said, "I am better than him. You created me from fire and created him from clay."
>
> 7:13 [ Allah ] said, "Descend from Paradise, for it is not for you to be arrogant therein. >So get out; indeed, you are of the debased.
>
> 7:14 [Satan] said, "Reprieve me until the Day they are resurrected."
>
> 7:15 [ Allah ] said, "Indeed, you are of those reprieved."
>
> 7:16 [Satan] said, "Because You have put me in error, I will surely sit in wait for them >on Your straight path.
>
> 7:17 Then I will come to them from before them and from behind them and on their right and >on their left, and You will not find most of them grateful [to You]."
>
> 7:18 [ Allah ] said, "Get out of Paradise, reproached and expelled. Whoever follows you >among them - I will surely fill Hell with you, all together."

As you may relies this is similar to a conversation (Allah knows best), between god and Satan and it is a blessing for us to have been informed of such knowledge by the almighty god to warn us of Satans evil plans.

So some versus can be a quote of what the devil has said, but this doesn't mean that the devil has included them there, but Allah SWT by his wisdom has chosen to embed them within the Quran as a warning for us humans the sons of Adam.

> 7:27 O children of Adam, let not Satan tempt you as he removed your parents from Paradise, >stripping them of their clothing to show them their private parts. Indeed, he sees you, he >and his tribe, from where you do not see them. Indeed, We have made the devils allies to >those who do not believe.